# How to share functions between an add on and a Sheets bound script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have a couple of script files that are currently being used inside a Sheet bound script via libraries. However, when a user that does not have access to the independent script files tries to open the spreadsheet and utilize it, he is not able to. For this reason, I am trying to deploy the code as an add on, instead of as a library.

Is it possible to get access to the functions inside the independent scripts via the add-on, just as I would do with a library? Would this solve the permissions issue? Is there a better alternative?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your question is unclear. But, I don't think you would be able to directly access bound unpublished  scripts from a addon.  You may be able to access it, if it was published as webapp, api or a library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.